When to use Fell vs Pelz to refer to fur?
I have conflicting information on what vocabulary to use when referring to an animal's fur. There is a note in the dictionary stating that Fell is for "fur with fewer than 400 hairs per square cm, e.g. on a dog, cat, or deer" and another saying that Pelz is "thick fur, e.g. on a bear or fox." However I see that there is also an entry for "Fuchsfell," as well as several instances of this term found on linguee.com, suggesting that a fox's fur is not always called "Pelz."
With other animals it seems less ambiguous, for example I see that the fur of a wolf or boar is "Fell" but I am still wondering about that of a fox.

"Fell" is if the skin of an animal is covered completely with hair (a "coat"). Those hairs can be short or long, more or less thick, but they cannot be sparse. E.g. a domesticated pig has still some sparse hairs on its skin, this is not a "Fell". Contrarily, the coat of a wild pig, which covers its skin completely, is.
"Fell" is also used for the skin of an animal with its hairs left on it. A "Rinderfell" (or "Bärenfell", etc.) could be something you hang as a decoration onto the wall or as a rug on the floor. "Lammfell" was used to cover car seat so that you are warmed from below before electric heating elements in seats became common.
The translation of "Pelz" is "fur" and is a "Fell", but one that is made of longer hair and usually doesn't lay smoothly on the skin. E.g. a bear or a sheep has a "Fell", which is also a "Pelz", a cat has a "Fell", but that is (usually) not called a "Pelz".
The matters are complicated because there is no exact boundary which "Fell" is also a "Pelz" and which isn't. At any rate, "Fell" is the more general word - in general.
Notice that there are a few fixed phrases which use "Pelz" as a synonym for "hide":

[jemandem] (eins) auf den Pelz brennen

verbatim to burn (one) onto someones/-things fur, meaning "to shoot (and hit) him/it". This is used metaphorically and works for people and animals with or without any real fur.
I have also heard

aus dem Pelz schlagen

meaning to beat someone (or an animal) up badly. This doesn't care either if what you beat out of its fur really sports one or not.
Lastly there is:

der Wolf im Schafspelz

which means someone posing as a friend (the sheep) but being a fiend in reality (the wolf hiding in the sheeps skin).

Does it make a difference if the fur is no longer attached to the skin, e.g. if there is a clump of fur lying on the ground?

@odduse_of_language: yes, it does. Hairs not attached to the skin any more might be called "Wolle" (wool), maybe "Haare" (hair), but not "Pelz" (fur). "Pelz" is hair attached to the skin or, at least, a skin-like underground. There is "Kunstpelz" (artificial fur) which is artificially made fur-like material, e.g. for coats or jackets, but even that makes the impression of hair attached to some underlying skin.

I'd also say that "Pelz" stresses the aspect of the fur as a product of trading/merchandise (for clothes etc). "Jemandem eins ueber den Pelz braten" is the aspect of ruining the quality of the fur of someone else (metaphorically) in the eyes of a hunger.

@R.J.Mathar: sorry, R.J., but that is not the case: there is even the term "Pelztiere" for animals sporting a "Pelz" - definitely not a "product of trading/merchandise".

Well, Pelztiere is all the animals with fur, because historically the aspect of selling/trading these skins was more important than some other aspects. A hunter who shoots these animals for meat (bison, deer) says "Wildtiere". If the animals are groomed (Alpaka, Vincuna, sheep) we say "Wolle" or "Fell". Beavers and seals are "Pelztiere" because their skin is sold. Tigers and lions are "Raubtiere" because their dangerous aspect is dominant.

Summarising somewhat what Janka and Bakunin have already said,

"Fell" seems to be a neutral word, and also sometimes technical, i.e. biological.
"Pelz" refers to fur under the aspect that it keeps someone warm. This applies both to furcoats and to certain types of fur of living animals. Therefore, this will be long-haired fur.

This would predict that often Pelz is used when talking about clothes, esp. a furcoat. For coats this is true. But dwds.de also has entries "Fellmütze, Felljacke, Fellkapuze, Fellkragen". While these would indeed not involve long-haired fur (especially the collar), consider the ceremonial busby worn by the Foot Guards ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_guards#/media/File:Sergio_Mattarella_al_Rideau_Hall_08.jpg ). This is a very hairy object, but the established German word is "Bärenfellmütze", not Pelzmütze. I would speculate that this is because the focus is on the kind of material, which is relevant to the ceremonial purpose, but here the function of keeping the soldiers warm is not the relevant aspect... Otherwise, "Pelzmütze" exists, but it evokes something you wear to keep you warm in winter.

"Pelz" is cognate to "pelt" in English, and "pelt" has a similar connotation of being furrier than "skin" or "hide", for example "beaver pelt" vs. "cow hide". But there are exceptions, for example "sheepskin" despite sheep being where wool comes from. So in both languages there seem to be cases where common usage overrides logic. Perhaps this is one of those cases where there seems to be a general trend, but there are too many exceptions for it to be very useful and you just have to memorize which word is associated with which animal on a case by case basis.

Pelz is a term from tailoring. It describes a very thick kind of Fell that is suited for tailoring clothes from it.

Die Dame trug einen Pelzmantel.
Die Dame trug einen Fellmantel.

And this term is also used for the fur of those animals when they still have it.

Er brannte dem Petz eins auf den Pelz.


So if I have a set of boots that are lined with fur, is it called Pelz?

Yes, with the exception of Lammfell. That's a fixed term.

@janka Except it's from a Karakul sheep. That's a Pelz. Yes, language is complicated.

There's some more exeptions as Bärenfellmütze. That's those top hats the British Royal Guards wear.

What does "er brannte dem Petz eins auf den Pelz" mean?

Meister Petz or short Petz is the fable name of the bear. And jemandem eins auf den Pelz brennen means shooting at someone.

NGram findet einige "das Fell des Bären" aber kein "den Pelz des Bären" (was man nicht verkaufen soll, bevor man das Tier erlegt hat).
